# Unique email model asp .net Code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to use the Remote function but it doesn work.

This is my code:

**Model**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "L'email est obligatoire.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "email n'est pas valide.")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[Remote("IsEmailAdminExist", "Admin", ErrorMessage = "Email exist!")]
public virtual  string Email { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult IsEmailAdminExist(string Email)
{
    return Json(!AdminContext.admins.Any(a => a.Email == Email), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

I don't have anything in return.

This is my form in **View** i use the Html.BeginForm

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AdminController", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form2", @role = "form", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                                <div class="col-md-4">

                                    <div class="form-group @(ViewData.ModelState["Email"] != null &&  Html.ViewData.ModelState["Email"].Errors.Any() ? "has-error" : "")">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Email <span class="symbol required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "help-block" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <div class="row">
                                   <div class="col-md-8">
                                       </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                         <button class="btn btn-yellow btn-block" type="submit" name="Create">
                                        Register <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                       </button>
                                     </div>
                               </div>
                       }
```

Comment: Did you enable UnobtrusiveJavaScript, and include jquery.validate.*.js files?

Comment: yes i enable UnobtrusiveJavaScript and ClientValidation

Comment: Show the scripts you have included in the view. The code you have shown works fine.

Comment: Did you mean javascript  code ?

Comment: @MalekBenelouafi, you must include `jquery-{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your view (or the layout) in order for the `[Remote]` attribute to work

Comment: it should include this validation jquery ? because i have my validation file in the project

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jDosx.png

Answer (score 0):

**Check your configuration**

I would make sure that you have the proper configuration settings in your `web.config` file to ensure that remote / client-side validation is performed :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

You'll also want to ensure that you have the proper client-side validation libraries referenced as well (`jquery.{version}.js` and `jquery.validate.{version}.js` respectively).

**Check your calls**

You may want to consider using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser to monitor the network traffic and ensure that the request is actually being made (you can do this by placing a breakpoint within your `IsEmailAddressExists()` call as well.

You should be seeing a request that looks something like the following :

```
~/Admin/IsEmailAdminExist?Email={your-email-value}
```

If this doesn't appear, check for any errors in the Console tab, which might shed some light on why the request isn't being made.

**Ensure casing isn't an issue**

You may want to consider ignoring case when checking for your other values as differing cases could cause the `Any()` method to fail as it wouldn't find the proper value. Try using [`ToLower()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) to make your comparisons case-insensitive and to ignore any extra white-space :

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult IsEmailAdminExist(string Email)
{
    // Clean up your e-mail
    var email = Email.ToLower.Trim();
    return Json(!AdminContext.admins.Any(a => a.Email.ToLower() == email), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Check your email validation logic**

Do you want to return if a user with this e-mail address already exists? If so, then you will want to actually return `true` if one does exist, so you wouldn't need the negation `!` prior to your call :

```
// If any exists, this will return true
Json(AdminContext.admins.Any(a => a.Email.ToLower() == email), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Otherwise, your current code is correct (i.e. it will return `false` if a user already exists with that name).

Comment: i fix my code, and now the IsEmailAdminExist return true but the email add ed without verification

Comment: If you output `true` from the function then it will pass validation and continue on to your function. So if you enter a valid that *should* be returning false, then maybe you should be using the `!` negation to get the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: the problem still exist, i think that the function is not taken by the **Model**

Comment: `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` is also required.

Comment: I dont have this file in my project